# OpenGL control overlays WPF elements

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl, devexpress, opentk

I have rich client application developed in WPF using DevExpress controls library.

In one of the panels I render some visual elements using OpenTK (OpenGL's wrapper library for .net).

The problem is, OpenGL rendering surface seems to be Top Most within the application. So if I move one panel on to another, OpenGL's control overlays WPF elements:

[image]

I'm not sure is it general problem with WPF, or something with DevExpress or OpenTK.

I would like to know, is there anything I can do, to solve this problem?

Edit: I'm using WindowsFormsHost control to put OpenTK's GLControl into WPF UserControl. And I'm using .Net 4.5.

Comment: Sounds and looks like the airspace issue. How are you using OpenTK? Via a `WindowsFormsHost` ?

Comment: @Roel van Westerop: Yes. I have WindowsFormsHost inside UserControl, and GLControl inside WindowsFormsHost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DockLayoutManager has [**known limitations**](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7551) when working with WindowsFormsHost. These limitations are general for WPF platform and they are powered by the current implementation of [HwndHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.aspx) (see [WPF and Win32 Interoperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx) MSDN-article for details).

You can try to overcome possible issues with dock panels overlapped by your OpenGL (WinForms) controls, by setting the [DockLayoutManager.EnableWin32Compatibility property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingDockLayoutManager_EnableWin32Compatibilitytopic) to `true` and the [DockLayoutManager.FloatingMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingDockLayoutManager_FloatingModetopic) property to `FloatingMode.Desktop`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will verify it tomorrow.

Comment: Happy to hear that my assistance was helpful ;-)